# Excel: How can I easily continue the numbering of a variable filename

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column:
[image]

How can I easily make all the rows below continue the counting of the filename? 
I have about 90 rows to fill like this and I really don't feel like doing it by hand. Selecting the column and dragging the lower-right corner doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ROW() to return the number part:

```
="/backgrounds/background(" & Row(1:1) & ").png"
```

Put that in the first cell and copy down.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. @spikey_richie has also provided a great answer, but this is easier and much more clean. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would put in column **A2**: `"/backgrounds/background ("`

In column **B2**: `"1"`

In column **C2**: `").png"`

In **D2** `=concatenate(A2,B2,C2)`

Then in **B3** `=B2+1` and drag that down, then drag down A, C & D.

D should then show your expected outcome

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edit Scott.